# How can we open a Html page after clicking on Menu bar button in specific part of window?

Tags: html

After clicking on menu the specific html page should get open on one part of window how can I do this with div tag?
can you please tell me  some example?
Right now I am doing this with the help of Frame tag but there is another alternative for it
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include the reference to the div you want to target with an id, for example:

```
<a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/card/#list-groups">Link</a>
```

You can see in there, the last part says `#list-group`, this is a reference to a section with an `id` of `list-groups` in the Bootstrap components page; you would have to do the same; specify an id to the section you want to go to; and when the page opens it will go to that section.

So something like:

```
<a href="another_page/#your_section_id">Link</a>
```

Will open the page and target a section on that page that has this:

```
<div id="your_section_id"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand right you want to open a pop-up on your page with html inside by clicking a button, you can do it in that way

```js
function openHtml()
{
   document.getElementById("html_block").innerHTML = "YourHTML..."; //simple way
   //$("#target_div").load("YOUR_PAGE.html"); //you can also use this to load html from file using jquery
}
```

```css
.main_page
{
 width: 100%;
 height: 200px;
 background: grey;
 position: relative;
}
#html_block
{
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  left: 80%; /*your specific position*/
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_page">
  <button onclick="openHtml()">open html</button>
  <div id="html_block"></div>
</div>
```